# Haskell Memory Leak Help (Glut State)

Tags: haskell, state, glut, memory-leaks

I have the smallest code, and have two problems, though only one matters right now. That one is that I have a memory leak with virtually zero code. The other being that glut's forcing me to use unsafePerformIO just so that I can have an IORef I can use within the callbacks (no parameters so it needs to be global). And yes I copied some from that tutorial.

(don't worry about the spacing):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification,
             TemplateHaskell,
             BangPatterns,
             RecursiveDo,
             GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving,
             MagicHash #-}
module Game
( Game (..)
) where
import Entity
import Util
import GUtil
import Resources
import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL hiding (get)
import Graphics.UI.GLUT hiding (get)
import Data.IORef
import qualified System.IO.Unsafe --I'm so so sorry, it's to initialize some global references since the callbacks don't have parameters

data Game = Game
          { _root :: Entity
          , _resources :: [Resource]
          }
$(makeLenses ''Game) 

gameRef :: IORef Game
gameRef = System.IO.Unsafe.unsafePerformIO (newIORef $ (Game (Entity ENull EDataNull []) []))

main :: IO ()
main = do
    (progname, _) <- getArgsAndInitialize
    createWindow "Hello World"
    idleCallback $= doUpdateGame
    displayCallback $= display
    reshapeCallback $= Just reshape
    mainLoop
reshape s@(Size w h) = do
    viewport $= (Position 0 0, s)
    postRedisplay Nothing

display :: IO ()
display = do
    clear [ ColorBuffer ]
    flush

doUpdateGame :: Maybe (IO ())
doUpdateGame = Just $ do
                modifyIORef gameRef (snd . runState updateGame)
updateGame :: State Game ()
updateGame = do 
                return ()
```

Where in this tiny bit of code is any problem that can cause a leak?

Comment: Great, so what's your question?

Comment: What's causing this because I have near zero code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a global unsafe `IORef`, just use partial application.

Rough and untested code:

```
idleCallback $= (doUpdateGame someLocalIORef)

...

doUpdateGame :: IORef Game -> Maybe (IO ())
doUpdateGame gameRef = Just $ modifyIORef gameRef (snd . runState updateGame)
```

Also, nothing appears to be forcing that `IORef` to be evaulated, so that's probably the space leak. Try profiling if some obvious strictness annotations don't help.

Comment: Yeah I forgot IORefs could change value and I could just pass it once